# Negative indents don't work?

Tags: css-paged-media, antenna-house

I'm using CSS Paged Media to create a PDF. Most of my content is aligned normally, but I have a few paragraphs I want to give a negative indent: they should start 2.5 mm to the left of everything else.

This is my CSS so far:

```
h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 2.5mm;
    text-indent: -2.5mm;
}
```

This is the intended effect:

[image]

When I try the above in Antennahouse (6.5), the left edge of the red background block remains lined up with the left edge of the text "This service manual..."

So `text-indent: -2.5mm;` doesn't seem to be working as I expect. How can I get the effect I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Drop the `padding-left` and use:

```
margin-left: -2.5mm;
text-indent: 2.5mm;
```

Or drop the `text-indent` and use:

```
margin-left: -2.5mm;
padding-left: 2.5mm;
```

The effect is the same in this case.  It's the negative `margin-left` that moves the left edge of the block area for the `h2` to the left.

The result shown in AH Formatter GUI (with area borders shown):

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that my code wasn't working because there was a more specific selector (out of sight in a second css file) `h2.heading2` that had `margin-left: 0mm`.